# Floor plans and locations in the Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft365

How can I access locations and floor plans through the Microsoft Graph API? They are part of Microsoft 365 **Search & Intelligence**, but I don't see any option under the search API.

For the record the Graph Explorer can be found here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To access the location info, "officeLocation" api "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/officeLocation" should help. you can find documentation here under users ->https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/users?view=graph-rest-1.0#common-properties

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I believe that API retrieves the office code (building/room) in the user's profile. What I am after is the full list of locations (including for example the locations where there are no users)., with the addresses. See my screenshot for how to access that info through the UI.

Comment: Just to confirm, I ran the query on the sample data. It returned "value": "12/1110", which is as expected the office code (building/room).

Comment: Can you please share the app details that you have under the integrated apps?

Comment: I don't have anything under integrated apps and I don't think it is related to the question. I believe it's highlighted because it is a new feature. Floor plans and locations are under "Search and Intelligence", as you can see from the title on the top right in the screenshot.

Comment: Unfortunately  the floor plan and listing of all  org location is  not yet available. If this is something important, please file a request for this on Uservoice: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis.